# Why amount zero in paypal integration?

Tags: php, html, paypal, payment-gateway

I have post variable like this(from firebug)

```
amount: 10.00
bn: PP-BuyNowBF
business:   payments@mymail.com
cancel_return:  http://localhost/ebin/Spacelance/
cmd:    _xclick-subscriptions
currency_code:  USD
invoice:    50d0317a74ba3
item_name:  suite number
item_number:    1
lc: IND
no_note:    1
no_shipping:    1
notify_url: http://localhost/ebin/Spacelance/
return: http://localhost/ebin/Spacelance/home/paypal_subscripton
```

in my paypal page the amount is
$0.00 USD. whats the problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

`amount` is not a valid parameter for `_xclick-subscription`.
You can find the correct parameters for subscriptions at https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-subscribe.html

Answer (score 0):

a3 is the parameter to be used for amount.

---

a3 - amount to billed each recurrence

p3 - number of time periods between each recurrence

t3 - time period (D=days, W=weeks, M=months, Y=years)

---

Example: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside